# Proper way to format user-entered text input for sending via JSON/AJAX to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm running into some problems with user-entered input that I want to send to PHP as JSON via AJAX that contains special characters, like ", ', etc.  I'm sending the contents of an array (used for slickgrid), and everything works fine unless those characters are included.  I know that PHP has the handy function mysql_real_escape_string, but is there any sort of jquery analogue?  Here is the relevant code:

```
req = $.ajax({
 url: url,
 dataType: "text",
 data: {"data": $.JSON.encode(data)},
 type: "post",
 success: onSaveSuccess,
 error: onSaveError
});
```

Here's the PHP it is submitted to:

```
<?php
//$data = array();

//if (isset($_POST['data']))
//{
 //$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
//}

//header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
//echo json_encode($data);
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

To be clearer, when special characters are included, neither the success nor error events are triggered.

I looked in firebug and it doesn't appear to send anything at all when the special characters are included...  Of course, it does when it's just letters or something.

Comment: Can't you just do `mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['var']))`?

Comment: It doesn't make it to PHP in the first place, so no...

Comment: Oh, I gotcha. Because of the commas in the string.

Comment: jQuery will handle proper escaping of the payload for you. You don't need to _and_ should not do any further escaping on the UI side. You should use mysql_real_escape_string on the deserialized JSON payload at the backend. Perhaps showing bits of your PHP code would help.

Comment: Ok, I showed how it is currently.  I do nothing but print_r($_POST).  I have an event hooked to "saving" when the request is sent, that gets triggered... then nothing.  Neither the success nor error events trigger from the AJAX.  The offending string in the data I'm sending looks something like: '",.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  It's due to the script I'm using to convert objects into JSON (that I found at http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2009/12/30/json-jquery-plugin/).  Switching to json2.js and using JSON.stringify has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the script from [here](http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2009/12/30/json-jquery-plugin/) apparently failing on certain kinds of input.  Switching to json2.js and using JSON.stringify has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {"data": $.JSON.encode(data)},
```

Passes up a more complex JSON object than you need.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Is looking for a serialized JSON object but jQuery is doing a lot of work for you in the background.

Try this

```
data: $.JSON.encode(data),
```

In your AJAX call. Then in PHP

```
$data['myPostValue'] = $_POST['myPostValue'];
```

You're sending a JSON object to the `$.ajax` call, and it is changing it into the name value pair that the server would normally get from a  post.

Answer (score -1):

javascript has an `escape()` function.  you can `$.JSON.encode(escape(data))` might work

Comment: Probably not. The `escape()` function is [not recommended](http://timothy.green.name/links/comparing-javascript-escapes/).